# Re: ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, importerror, descriptor

I am running following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

I am getting following error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall tensorflow
```

This will make sure to uninstall and reinstall the program from fresh.